# MATLAB Serial incorrectly sending values

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am trying to communicate with a StepRocker motor controller/drive using MATLAB. I have figured out how to format their commands and have been able to get it to move to many of commands. Their commands require that the values be sent in a binary format over RS-232. I started running into some issues and started using an Arduino to echo my commands.

I am currently sending the values 1 - 255 just to test sending bytes over the serial channel. I am sending it to an Arduino and reading the bytes back out of the Arduino. All numbers work except for the numbers between 128 and 159. This is problematic since some of my commands require values in this range.

MATLAB Script:

```
obj = instrfind; delete(obj);       % cleanup any lost objects
clear; close force all; clc;        % clear the workspace

sM = serial('COM2','BaudRate',9600, 'Terminator', 'CR', 'Timeout', 10);
fopen(sM);

pause(2);                           % give port time to open

% make list of numbers 1-255, skip 10/13 since they terminate on the
% arduino
cmd = [1:9 11:12 14:255];

% Send command and get echo
fprintf(sM,cmd);
pause(0.5);                         % give time for echo
echo = fscanf(sM);
uint8(echo)

fclose(sM);
```

After executing this script I get the following output:

```
ans =

  Columns 1 through 22

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   11   12   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24

  Columns 23 through 44

   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45   46

  Columns 45 through 66

   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68

  Columns 67 through 88

   69   70   71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89   90

  Columns 89 through 110

   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109  110  111  112

  Columns 111 through 132

  113  114  115  116  117  118  119  120  121  122  123  124  125  126  127   63   63   63   63   63   63   63

  Columns 133 through 154

   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63   63

  Columns 155 through 176

   63   63   63  160  161  162  163  164  165  166  167  168  169  170  171  172  173  174  175  176  177  178

  Columns 177 through 198

  179  180  181  182  183  184  185  186  187  188  189  190  191  192  193  194  195  196  197  198  199  200

  Columns 199 through 220

  201  202  203  204  205  206  207  208  209  210  211  212  213  214  215  216  217  218  219  220  221  222

  Columns 221 through 242

  223  224  225  226  227  228  229  230  231  232  233  234  235  236  237  238  239  240  241  242  243  244

  Columns 243 through 254

  245  246  247  248  249  250  251  252  253  254  255   13
```

Looking at the output, you can see that the numbers between 128 and 159 all come through as 63. I am at a loss for what is causing this issue. This is very repeatable, and the problem occurs anytime there is a number in this range, no matter its position in the string, no matter the length of the serial string.

Arduino Code:

```
bool stringComplete = false;
String inputString = "";

void setup() {                
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (stringComplete) {
    Serial.print(inputString);
    stringComplete = false;
    inputString = "";
  }
}

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    inputString += inChar;
    if (inChar == '\r') {
       stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: What does *echo* look like if you don't cast it into *uint8*?

Comment: char(63) is '?'. I am guessing those are not recognized, so return a question mark. You may try fprintf(sM, char(128)) or fprintf(sM, uint8(128)), and check the echo.

Comment: 1. Not as uint8:
  !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~???????????????????????????????? ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ

Comment: 2. Trying fprintf(sM,char(128)):

`fprintf(sM,char(128));
echo = fscanf(sM);
disp(echo);

?`

The output is still a question mark for char(128)

Comment: 3. Try fprintf(sM,uint8(128))

MATLAB gives following error:
`Error using serial/fprintf (line 123)
CMD must be a string.`

Comment: Could you try one more thing: fprintf(sM,char(128)); echo = fscanf(sM, '%i'); or fprintf(sM,char(128)); fread(sM, 1, 'uint8');

Comment: Both of those just result in the ? again

Comment: Last test, then if no luck, I will blame the firmware. fwrite(sM, 128, 'uint8'); fread(sM, 1, 'uint8');

Comment: That got it to work! Thanks